# css border-radius to crop a off-center circle

Tags: css

How to use css border-radius to crop a circle from a rectangular image **when the circle is not at center of the image**?

Green is the photo {w,h}.  Portrait w:h = 3:4.

Red is the area to be shown.  circle center {x,y} = say {0.5w, 0.3h}, origin is at top-left.

[image: green is the photo, use css to show only the red circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method achieved by cropping a background-image and setting its position. Obviously there's some trial and error involved here in getting it to line up, but hopefully you wouldn't need to calculate something like this programmatically.

Let me know if this helps!

```css
.circle {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0V1X.png');
  background-position: 48% 11.75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```